# Making colored hillshade in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, hillshade, color-ramp

Today I found that ArcGis can make colored hillshade like on piture below.

[image: Official link]

Here is [link](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-pro/mapping/throwing-shade/) to their blog. I want to do that in QGIS. I know about layer coloring feature, and it's close for perfect, but it can use just one color. So maybe there is some plugin for QGIS with that I can use color *scheme* (color ramp) instead one color.

---

I'm done it! Here is my result:

[image]

Not so good like a result from ArcGis blog, but I'm on the right way!

**What I've done?**

Firstly, I've created a new hillshade layer, with Hillshade tool, as noted in the answer. Then, I've choosed pseudocolor style in the properties of this layer. Of course I've applied color ramp similar to one from the blog. Finally, I've repeated all three layers from the blog, and made them all 50% transparent. Done.

Comment: simply apply a color ramp to your hill shade layer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a multidirectional hillshade with different colors for each direction you can:

1. Create three separate hillshades with different azimuts, for example 315, 15, 75 using Hillshade tool under Raster terrain analysis
2. Combine these using Build Virtual Raster under Miscellanous with option Place each input file into a separate band

[image]

Comment: Thank you! You gave me a right advice! Actually I have no need to combine them, but the first item of your message is completely right.